# StyleCop error as "Specified Method is not Supported" when run stylecop in .net core + angular template project

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, stylecop

I have created .net core + angular template project and installed stylecop extension. When i added a file(.ts) inside my angular project(Clientapp/src/app) then following code is generated

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="ClientApp\src\app\counter\file.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\src\app\counter\file.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And When i run stylecop by right clicking on project I got following error in popup.

"Specified method is not supported"

If I remove above code form .proj file and run stylecop everything start working fine.

Can someone suggest any solution for this. How to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by incompatible versions. Do you add some methods in this file?